Module CSS isolation in Blazor
Is it possible to implement CSS isolation within module scope?
For example, we have an Authorization module which contains several components like: Login, ResetPassword, etc.
They all have similar structure so it would be good to create common styles for them, and these styles shouldn't be able to be used outside of module.

What do you mean by shouldn't be able to be used outside? If to be referenced by components, simply place it n your module shared directory. To be more isolated, make it a library would be feasible. However if want to be locked from being accessed by files outside, in my research it is not supported.
